# When processing an ACH payment, how do I know when the money is cleared and is part of my available balance?

Tags: stripe-payments

When processing an ACH payment in Stripe, how do I know when the payment has completed and cleared the banking system? The payment "succeeds" immediately, but the funds aren't available in my balance for up to 5 or 6 days. And I don't see any way for me to know when that is completed. I need to set a status in my platform that the payment has been completed.

I've looked at various Stripe events and don't see any that are obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to `balance.available` webhook events to get notified when funds are available in your account for payouts.

Comment: Thanks, but balance.available just tells me the balance is changed. It doesn't tell me the specific ACH has completed.

Comment: If you want to get notified for a specific payment. You can listen to `payment_intent.succeeded`, from there get the latest_charge->balance_transaction. Its available_on (https://docs.stripe.com/stripe-apps/build-backend#receiving-events-webhooks) tells you when funds become available in your Stripe account.

Comment: payment_intent.succeeded succeeds immediately. From there all I get are balance changes and I have no idea what it applies to. I could have 100 transactions that all succeeded and the balance changes for a tranche of them.